# c language with mysql( how to include mySQL database into program )

Tags: mysql, sql, c, database

I want to integrate MySQL database into my C program. 
Is there a possible way to do so ? What are the libraries that should be used ? (If it's possible)

Comment: How exactly did you link the libraries needed to your program? What format are they in?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

Comment: Why are you telling like that ha ?

Comment: Isn't that the way to include pre defined functions into C language ?

Comment: Mysql isn't a standard library, it is a 3rd party library. So unless you have a compiler/IDE which is doing all the work for you in locating the Mysql library, you have to link it to your program manually. The problems you get appear because the compiler can't find find the header files and likely not the library either. Which is why I asked how you have linked them to your program. If you have not, then no wonder you are getting errors...

Comment: I am using code blocks (IDE). But it does't have above header files. How can I include them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C API code is distributed with MySQL. It is included in the mysqlclient library and allows C programs to access a database.

Many of the clients in the MySQL source distribution are written in C. If you are looking for examples that demonstrate how to use the C API, take a look at these clients. You can find these in the clients directory in the MySQL source distribution.

Here is a small program that connects to a MySQL server and list all tables from the database:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   MYSQL *conn;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;
  /* Change me */
   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "root";
   char *password = "PASSWORD";
   char *database = "mysql";

   conn = mysql_init(NULL);

   /* Connect to database */
   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }

   /* send SQL query */
   if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }

   res = mysql_use_result(conn);

   /* output table name */
   printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      printf("%s \n", row[0]);

   /* close connection */
   mysql_free_result(res);
   mysql_close(conn);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, as his compiler can't even locate the library.

Comment: it shows error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector with `row[0]`